# Creating multiple instances of class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public class Human
        {
            public string Name;
            public Human(string name)
            {
                Name = name;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Jane";
        }
        private void AddNewHuman_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Human h1 = new Human(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way, how to create a new instance of `Human` whenever I click the `Button(AddNewHuman_Click)`?

After clicking few times on the button, there will still be only one `Human h1`, right?

Comment: Yes there will always be only one human h1 this way. What you'd have to do is create a `List<Human>` outside the `AddNewHuman_Click` and add a new Human to this list inside the `AddNewHuman_Click`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create list of object to store multiple object of human class.

I do changed here for you. I hope it will work for you.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public class Human
    {
        public string Name;
        public Human(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
    List<Human> objHumanList;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        objHumanList=new List<Human>();
        textBox1.Text = "Jane";
    }
    private void AddNewHuman_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Human h1 = new Human(textBox1.Text);
        objHumanList.add(h1);

        /** Or

        objHumanList.add (new Human(textBox1.Text))

        **/
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of Humans and keep on adding a new Human to the list whenever the button is clicked.